# How can I detect when Control.PreferredSize changes?

Tags: winforms, controls

I'm using [Control.PreferredSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.preferredsize.aspx) in order to determine what the [ScrollableControl.AutoScrollMinSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscrollminsize.aspx) should be for a Form. This will need to be set whenever the control's PreferredSize property changes, but there doesn't appear to be a Control.PreferredSizeChanged event. Is there a way to detect when this property changes (possibly using [Control.WndProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx))? I would prefer to avoid polling the property if it can be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override OnLayout or OnPaint.

```
    private Size m_CurrentPreferedSize;
    protected override void OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLayout(e);
        Size newSize = PreferredSize;
        if(m_CurrentPreferedSize != newSize)
        {
           m_CurrentPreferedSize  = newSize;
           //Your code here 
        }
    }
```

PreferredSize is calculated on every call.

Comment: I'd rather not override OnPaint because that method is called so often. It's not clear that OnLayout is *guaranteed* to be called every time PreferredSize changes, but it does seem to work; I was unable to find a scenario that caused PreferredSize to change that did not also cause OnLayout to be called.