# Detecting Control.PreferredSize changes

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, scroll

I'm having the following scenario:
I have a `UserControl` `CustomControl`, which can be considered 3rd party (I have not access to the code to change the innards of this `CustomControl`). This control dynamically depending on the input of the user: A checkbox is used to hide some advanced settings. `CustomControl` has no events for me to latch on to that is related to showing the advanced properties.

This control is hosted in a `UserControl`, `Host`. `CustomControl` is docked (`Dock` = Fill) inside `Host`.

`Host` itself is used inside a dockable panel, and is expected to stretch from left edge to right edge. Because of this requirement, most other controls use `Dock` = Fill for this.

The problem is, that the hidden list of advanced properties is long enough to require a vertical scrollbar, but not when the advanced properties are hidden. Currently, due to `Host` being docked using Fill, no scroll-bars appears in the docking panel at all, causing some of the properties to fall off the screen and rendering `CustomControl` unusable.

I know that if I want to keep `CustomControl` docked using Fill inside of `Host`, then I need to use AutoScrollMinSize and have it be in sync with `Host`'s `PreferredSize`.
Because `CustomControl` can be considered 3rd party, the solution proposed in this link ([How can I detect when Control.PreferredSize changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400696/how-can-i-detect-when-control-preferredsize-changes)) is not an option for me. Listening to the `Layout` event did not seem to capture the dynamic hiding and revealing of cub-controls.

Comment: You don't say why listening to the Layout or Paint event won't work. If the CustomControl inherits from Control or UserControl those events should be available.  Have you tried adding a new OnLayout or OnPaint event handler to the CustomControl, or using a class that inherits CustomControl and overriding the OnLayout or OnPaint event handler?

Comment: @tinstaafl: I have subscribed to `Layout` event but is was not firing when the dynamic size change occurs. What I did notice, is that if you dig deep enough in the `Controls` collections, the visibility of individual subcontrols in `CustomControl` are changing (events firing). I'm guessing the effects on the subcontrols cause events to occur on `CustomControl` itself?

Comment: It might depend how the CustomControl is programmed.